# Ubuntu Security API request limit

Tags: security

Hi I'am trying to retrieve CVE information from different vendors. And found the [Ubuntu Security API](https://ubuntu.com/security/api/docs#/default/get_security_cves_json).

Does anyone know if it has a request limit?

Comment: Before DOS-ing the Ubuntu Security Team by trying to duplicate their entire database with tens of thousands of requests, [talk to them directly](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-hardened) and explain your project. They are very nice folks and might be able to offer you a better and simpler solution.

Comment: hahaha, wasn't the idea to bypass them. I'am awating for their response.

Comment: There response?  Have you asked them? as don't forget this is a user support site? as so far I only see requests for help to other users.  They have multiple areas where they are open for questions (they publish them ~weekly in the Ubuntu Security Podcast & other publications) but this user Q&A site isn't ever mentioned.

Comment: You do realize Ubuntu 20.10 (*groovy*) was a non-LTS & is thus [well out of support](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/); it was the first non-LTS in the cycle (of 3) that started with 20.10 & concluded in the release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. If you were trying to include 3 releases from full cycles; 18.04, 20.04 & 22.04 makes more sense (*at least to me*)

Comment: Hi guys, today I was talking to one representative of Canonical. Their security API doesn't have a request limit or cost of use.

Comment: please make it an answer, upvote and accept it. That way the system will clear it from its queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today I was talking to one representative of Canonical. Their security API doesn't have a request limit or cost of use.

Also the API and the OVAL format provide the same information.